# Using LEFT for an array of letters

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the LEFT formula to find if the text contains the letters L through Z.

I know to find L I would use:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,1)="L", "Yes", "No")
```

How would I include the letters L-Z without typing out each individual letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
=IF(B2>="L*", "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(SUM(IF(LEFT(B2,1)={"L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},1,0)),"Yes","No")
```

Slightly shorter version (use `Search` instead of `Find` to make it case insensitive)

```
=IFERROR(T(FIND(LEFT(B2,1),"LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))&"Yes","No")
```

---

If you really want to to a pattern like `L-Z` then you can write a VBA User Defined Function(UDF)

```
Function IsLike(str As Variant, Patt As String) As Boolean
    IsLike = str Like Patt
End Function
```

and use it like this

```
=IF(IsLike(LEFT(B2,1),"[L-Z]"),"Yes","No")
```

or case insensitive

=IF(IsLike(LEFT(B3,1),"[l-zL-Z]"),"Yes","No")

Comment: My original post should have said without typing out each individual letter. I tried to use L:Z, L-Z, and L.Z with no luck. I figured they might have a way to achieve this, but possibly not.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(B2)={"L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}), "yes", "no")
```

... or,

```
=if(and(code(b2)>=76, code(b2)<=90), "yes", "no")
```

This latter formula is case-sensitive but you could change CODE(B2) to CODE(UPPER(B2)) in both places to make it case-insensitive.

If you don't want to deal with ASCII character codes and can be satisfied with a case-insensitive comparison then Excel's Quick Sort algorithm seems to suffice.

```
=if(and(left(b2)>="L", left(b2)<="Z"), "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a range for L-Z, and use a combination of ISNUMBER() and MATCH(), e.g. =ISNUMBER((MATCH(C2,A1:A15))).

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear on why TEST fails. Surely T (and S) is between L and Z.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the requirement. If you are looking if the text contains any letters from L to Z, then I think MATCH() can be used instead, please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

This will look for lower and upper case...

`=IF(AND(LEFT(B1,1)>=CHAR(76),LEFT(B1,1)<=CHAR(90)),"Yes","No")`

These character codes are for the upper case but excel returns the lower case as true as well.

If for some reason your excel wont return the lower case as true then just use this

`=IF(OR(AND(LEFT(B2,1)>=CHAR(76),LEFT(B2,1)<=CHAR(90)),AND(LEFT(B2,1)>=CHAR(108),LEFT(B2,1)<=CHAR(122))),"Yes","No")`